# What is this in-game artwork of Monokuma referencing?

Tags: danganronpa

I've been playing Danganronpa: Ultra Despair Girls recently and I came across these two pieces of art in game:

[image]

[image]

You can probably tell from the picture, but the pannels are in a zigzag layout - and you have to look at it from a particular angle to get the full picture.

The first picture looks familar, but obviously it has monokumas in it instead of the original characters/thing - the second one seems to be a picture of Towa City - where the game is set, and might not be related. But seeing as it was the other side of the panels, I thought the text might be relevant.

**What is the original artwork that the Monokumas have taken over?**

Comment: The text reads: "おいでませ 塔和タワー", which means "Welcome to Towa Tower". I'm not sure whether it has anything to do with the original image (or if it do reference anything), though.

Comment: hmm, I guess it's probably unrelated - as I think the screenshot is taken from inside the tower

Comment: For those interested: The text in the first image reads "ものくま" or "Monokuma"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it may be a monokuma version of the official 'Danganronpa Girls' / 'Danganronpa Boys' artworks

[image]

[image]

I'm not sure if the offical-ness of the male version, but both seem to have the characters bunched up on one side, with some small effect in front of them. In the monokuma version, this is replaced with blood.

Comment: Who is the martial artist and the person holding branches in the "Danganronpa Boys"? I don't recognize them, and if you count them in addition to all the recognizable characters, it goes over the "known 16 students".

Comment: @Wimateeka Much belated answer, but - the martial artist is Kenshiro, Sakura Oogami's rival/crush. The man with the flowers is Santa Shikiba, who's mentioned briefly in DR1 as being a the Ultimate Botanist who created the Monokuma Flower in the garden on the fifth floor.